# Spring Parallel processing

Tags: spring, parallel-processing

I've a requirement wherein one flow works synchronously (request-response), while in the same app another set of flows polls on an external source for changing information. Can someone please advise how i can configure this using spring. I found Spring Batch, Camel, Spring Integration as the likely candidates for my requirement, wanted to know if they would help or if there are any other simpler or better solutions around?

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone suggest anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down a bit on what you are trying to do:

You want a simple app based on spring which can do multiple tasks (I wont use word parallel as inherently I think it's not your requirement - but elaborate more if you think it is)

- You can use Spring Web/REST for exposing services that you need in request-response model
- For polling certain events from an external source - depending on what is your external source, spring provides rich set of adapters which you can make to poll on event. For example if it's a filesystem where you are expecting some files to arrive then you would configure a file adapter and poller along with it.
- Spring integration is specifically targeted at integrating multiple systems and offers rich set of adapters - which is purely based on requirements.
- Spring batch is for tasks/jobs which you plan to run frequently and do mass data movement or changes and you want the infrastructure code out of the box!